# Strange behaviour in recursive copy

Tags: cp, recursive

Could someone explain why this happens?

Most specifically: 
Why is one 1's content copied to f?
And why is f copied to g?

```
$ tree  
.

0 directories, 0 files

$ mkdir 1
$ mkdir 2
$ touch 1/a
$ touch 1/b
$ mkdir 1/c
$ touch 1/c/x
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
│       └── x
└── 2

3 directories, 3 files

$ cp -r 1/* 2/*
zsh: no matches found: 2/*

$ cp -r 1/* 2/*
$ mkdir 2/f
$ mkdir 2/g
$ cp -r 1/* 2/*
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
│       └── x
└── 2
    ├── f
    └── g
        ├── a
        ├── b
        ├── c
        │   └── x
        └── f

7 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: I think you have an extra `cp -r 1/* 2/*` in there - it's done twice in a row with (apparently) different results. It should always complain about not finding a `2/*` because the shell can't expand that glob - nothing matches it.

And the contents of `1` is not copied to `f` in this example.

Comment: If the destination of the `cp` is kind of ambiguous, you can try `--target-directory`, e.g. `cp --target-directory=2 fileglob1 fileglob2` I find that option very useful in scripts where I am not sure what globs will work and which ones won't; it helps prevent accidentally overwriting stuff. (Some versions of `cp` allow `-t` .)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `cp`, the destination is the last argument on the command line. You have specified `2/g` as the last argument.

Before `cp` is executed, the command parameters are expanded. `1/*` expands to `1/a 1/b 1/c`. `2/*` expands to `2/f 2/g`. The final executed command is `cp -r 1/a 1/b 1/c 2/f 2/g`, which will copy all the arguments (except the last one) to `2/g`.

If you are intending to copy things to `2`, the second glob isn't necessary, making the command `cp -r 1/* 2/`. If you are intending to copy things to multiple destinations, you can't specify that with just `cp`; you can use a small loop, like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
for path in ./2/*/; do
  cp -r 1/* "$path"
done
```